# networkx can't calculate algebraic connectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, networkx

I can compute the algebraic connectivity of the complete graph on 20 vertices in fraction of a second using

```
import networkx
D = {}
for i in range(20):
    D[i] = [j for j in range(20)]
G = networkx.Graph(D)
networkx.algebraic_connectivity(G)
```

However, in a process I generate a graph (on 20 nodes) that I ask networkx to compute its algebraic connectivity, and it keeps running for ever with no errors. Here is the graph:

```
import networkx

D = {0: [32, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 5: [32, 0, 33, 19, 37, 21, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 44, 28, 15, 31], 6: [0, 32, 33, 19, 5, 37, 21, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 11: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 15: [0, 32, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 31], 19: [0, 32, 33, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 21: [32, 0, 33, 19, 37, 5, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 22: [32, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 26: [0, 32, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 28: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 44, 15, 31], 31: [32, 0, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15], 32: [0, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 31, 15], 33: [0, 32, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 37: [32, 0, 33, 19, 5, 21, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 31, 15], 38: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 6, 22, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 39: [0, 32, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 6, 22, 38, 41, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 41: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 38, 6, 22, 39, 26, 42, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31],  42: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 11, 43, 28, 44, 15, 31], 43: [32, 0, 33, 19, 21, 37, 5, 6, 22, 38, 39, 41, 26, 42, 11, 28, 44, 15, 31], 44: [32, 0, 33, 19, 5, 21, 37, 38, 6, 22, 39, 41, 42, 26, 11, 43, 28, 15, 31]}

G = networkx.Graph(D)
networkx.algebraic_connectivity(G)
```

Any reasons why it is so, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the tracemin method that is the default with networkx.algebraic_connectivity().  Try using

```
networkx.algebraic_connectivity(G, method='lanczos')
```

Comment: That is a very easy fix. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: To add to Aric's remark, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2381) in `networkx`.